# FileSystemWatcher or Directory Read?

Tags: c#, architecture, windows-services

**Conext**

I have a scenario in which i have to check the specific directory after every 30 seconds for new files. If there is any new file then i have to process the files but can be multiple in a batch.

**Questions**

Should i use FileSystemWatcher or Read the directory and process the files in parallel ?

I am using Windows service which will process CSV files and output will be shown to windows form application.

- Can we schedule the FileSystemWatcher on Timer ?
- What will be the best approach in this case ?
- If i choose the Directory read instead of FileSystemWatcher how to process the batch of 100 files in parallel and send to other application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying and found this article interesting.

https://connectvishal.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/filesystemwatcher-and-queues-with-parallel-execution/

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)    
{    

    current_directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);    

    try   
    {    
        strDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory"];    
        fileMask = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileMask"];    
        strBatfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Batch"];    
        strlog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log"];    

        Task.Factory.StartNew(QueueHandler);    

        var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();    
        fsw.Created += (o, e) =>    
        {    
            // add a file to the queue    
            filenames.Enqueue(e.FullPath);    

        };    

        fsw.Path = strDir + "\\";    
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite    
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;    
        fsw.Filter = fileMask;    

        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;    
        fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleated);    
        fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);    


        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;    
    }    
    catch (Exception exception)    
    {    
        CustomException.Write(CustomException.CreateExceptionString(exception.ToString()));    
    }    

}
```

and a queue handler :

```
static void QueueHandler()    
{    
    bool run = true;    
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += (s, e) =>    
    {    
        run = false;    
        filenames.Enqueue("stop");    
    };    
    try   
    {    
        while (run)    
        {    
            string filename;    
            if (filenames.TryDequeue(out filename) && run)    
            {    
                var proc = new Process();    
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = Service1.strBatfile;   //here .exe can be added  
                proc.Start();    
               ;    
                Log.getLogger("File Processed after executing batch\.exe:  Filename - :" + filename + " " + "Batch File Executed- > " + Service1.strBatfile + " at timestamp : " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), Service1.strlog);    
                proc.WaitForExit(); // this blocks until the process ends....    

            }    
        }    
    }    
    catch (Exception exception)    
    {    
        CustomException.Write(CustomException.CreateExceptionString(exception.ToString()));    
    }
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Changed my answer

Comment: Thanks Vish, but can i use FileSystemWatcher on scheduling  because i have to collect the files in batch.

Comment: FileSystem watcher can be used with timer for scheduling.Or You can use Windows TaskScheduler if you want at specific time.I used Filesystem watcher as I wanted instant result.